# How to restrict iOS App if user device is not enroll with Airwatch Agent?

Tags: ios, mdm, airwatch

In android we can easily check the device is enrolled or not as follow :

```
final boolean isEnrolled = awSDKManager.isEnrolled();
if (isEnrolled) {
      final String settings = awSDKManager.getCustomSettings();
}
```

There is similar function for iOS platform, By which we can check user device have AIRWatch agent application installed or enrolled with that.

Please guide me.

Comment: No, you can't do anything like that because of the app sandbox. You should distribute the app via the MDM then you don't need to check. An application that requires the device to be enrolled wouldn't be suitable for dsitribution through the App Store anyway.

Comment: If we can't do this then how we verified that AIRWatch agent is installed on user device, Which is used by console to wipe or security purpose in enterprise distribution.
https://my.air-watch.com/help/9.1/en/Content/Expert_Guides/iOS_Swift_SDK/T/CleanInstallation.htm

Comment: you would check from the AirWatch console. What are you trying to achieve?  If you don't want the app to run on unmanaged devices, don't install it on unmanaged devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly initialize AWController for the AIRWatch integration in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

  AWController *controller = [AWController clientInstance];

  // 2) Defining the callback scheme so the app can get called back --
  // this should match the URL scheme you defined in "Callback Scheme Registration".
  controller.callbackScheme = @"awsdkcallback";
  controller.delegate = self;
  [controller start];

    return YES;
}
```

then use the following delegate method to check your device is enrolled or not

```
- (void) initialCheckDoneWithError: (NSError *) error {
  if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error in initialization: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        NSLog(@"Not enrolled on AirWatch agent");
  } else {
    NSLog(@"Initialization completed without error");
  }
```

}

**Update:** for Latest AirWatch SDK 18, Use the following method for the same:

```
 [controller queryDeviceEnrollmentStatus:^(BOOL isSucess, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Error is : %@",error.localizedDescription);
  }];
```